# Get access to SSMS in Home - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I already made some changes in Configuration Manager:

- Change Built-in account to **Local Service**;
- Enable all the protocols in SQL Server Network Configuration

And when I'm trying to access to the servername with windows authentication I'm getting the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to *_DESKTOP_*.


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
```

I run the command ipconfig/all and I get this:

[image]

What I should do next?

Thanks!

Comment: The SQL Server is not the same as your machine name. You should run the installer and find out what the server name is. Or try localhost and see if that works.

Comment: with localhost is the same error